# Citation graph tool

Tags: graph, ieee-754, bibliography, ieee, citations

Does anyone know a tool/app to make a citation graph, or some app that can make a graph with papers and their references, and bibliography of papers?

I was told, that ieee has one, but i didn't fid it.

Comment: If you'd like to develop such an app, that would be a programming question that is likely to be in-scope for Stack Overflow. I've written Python code to interpret downloads from the Scopus database that could be used to help you build citation graphing software, for instance. If you're looking for existing software that builds citation graphs, however, your question is probably not in-scope for Stack Overflow. You might start with the [Wikipedia entry on citation graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_graph).

Comment: You could also see [this answer on Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/190772/visualizing-document-citations-in-a-graph) which discusses using GraphViz to visualise the citation graph.

Answer (score 0):

You could build this with [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) using something like a [force-directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/4062045).

Adding the [fisheye distortion](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) makes for great visual effects (not necessarily useful, but cute).

If the citation graph is not connex, using [Colony](http://hughsk.github.com/colony/) is a great option.

As a sidenote, when looking for a visualization tool, I usually check the [D3.js Gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery). It's amazing.